# iterating over related objects in django

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   family=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MailContact(models.Model):
   person=models.ForeignKey(Person)
   email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   #some fields

class Participant(models.Model):
   person=models.ForeignKey(Person)
   #some fields
```

in `views.py` :

```
   emails = []
   for participant in participants:
      for contact in participant__person__mailContact_set:
         emails.append(contact.email)
   send_mail(email_subject,email_body,'receiver_email_address@gmail.com',emails,fail_silently=False)
```

I've changed this code in many ways but I'm repeatedly get this error:

```
global name 'participant__person__mailContact_set' is not defined
```

any suggestion?

Comment: he's just learning, why downvote ? The question is clear and he posted the relevant code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
for contact in participant.person.mailcontact_set.all():
```